# Ubuntu 18.04 no longer booting - I created a bootable USB with Ubuntu 20.04 - I can boot it from the usb

Tags: boot

I can see the data files I want to save to an external hard drive so that I can uninstall Ubuntu and re-install Ubuntu.
But when I try to copy these data files it talks about permissions.

Is there no simple way to recover the data and re-install Ubuntu.
I am tiered of trying things.
I would rather just uninstall and re-install

Comment: You don't need to uninstall; you can just install over your existing Ubuntu (you didn't say if desktop or server install) as a clean install (ie. no data is kept & your system is as if new), or replace your existing programs with fresh ones but keep your data & re-install your added applications (*the install type is controlled by whether or not you format assuming you're asking about a desktop install*).

Comment: Thank you for the help - but the real problem is that I can't get my data and save it before I over-right it.